# Are $X'\otimes Y$ and $\mathfrak L(X,Y)$ isomorphic?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, tensor-products

Let

- $\mathbb F\in\left\{\mathbb C,\mathbb R\right\}$
- $X$ and $Y$ be normed $\mathbb F$-vector spaces
- $X'$ be the topological dual space of $X$
- $\mathfrak L(X,Y)$ be the set of bounded, linear operators from $X$ to $Y$
- $\mathfrak B(X\times Y)$ be the set of bilinear forms on $X\times Y$

> Let $$(x\otimes y)(A):=A(x,y)\;\;\;\text{for }A\in\mathfrak B(X\times Y)$$ for $(x,y)\in X\times Y$ and $$X\otimes Y:=\operatorname{span}\left\{x\otimes y:(x,y)\in X\times Y\right\}\;.$$ Can we show that there is an isomorphism $\iota$ between $X'\otimes Y$ and $\mathfrak L(X,Y)$?

It's clear that any $u\in X'\otimes Y$ with $$u=\sum_{i=1}^n\varphi_i\otimes y_i$$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$ and $(\varphi_i,y_i)\in X'\times Y$ yields some $L\in\mathfrak L(X,Y)$ via $$L:=\varphi_iy_i\;.$$ However, is the mapping $X'\otimes Y\to\mathfrak L(X,Y)$ which maps $u$ to $L$ injective?

The other inclusion is not clear to me at all. However, the question arose as I saw people identifying $X'\otimes Y$ with $\mathfrak L(X,Y)$.

Answer (score 3):

The elements of $X'\otimes Y \subseteq \mathcal L(X,Y)$ all have finite rank and, in particular, are compact operators. There is thus no chance for equality if $X$ and $Y$ are infinite dimensional. If you take the closure of the tensor product in $\mathcal L(X,Y)$ you get (by definition) the *approximable* operators. This closure often coincides with all compact operators (e.g., for Hilbert spaces) but not always. This depends on the *approximation property* for $X$ and $Y$.